# Button click is again fired on reload

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

When page is reloaded it again goes to last event(e.g. Button click).Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: come on ! how do you think we can resolve your problem ? post some code or be more explicit.

Comment: My _guess_ is that button you clicked was part of a Form, and when you refresh a page, it usually re-submits the form ("goes to last event"). As @Andrew pointed out, if that's not the case, please provide more information, e.g. A better description of the problem and/or code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the page by 'refreshing' (F5), and clicking to accept the resubmission of values, the button click event firing again is by design.

If it's something else, we need much more information to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Response.Redirect to the current page in the end of your event handler.